# HTML import error

Tags: jquery, html

Im a newbie to Jquery and trying to learn it,
I have the following piece of code but for some reason my image is not loading. 
WHen I run the same link through my run command the image pops out. 
It says failed to load the given URL when I debugged thru firebug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Furry Friends Campaign</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:/jquery/Chapter-1/begin/styles/my_style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="clickMe">Show Me the Furry Friend of the Day</div>
    <div id="picframe">
     <img src="c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/images/img_0229.jpg">
   </div>
   <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clickMe").click(function() {
        $("img").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#picframe").slideToggle("slow");
   });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "file://c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/images/img_0229.jpg" as your image URL instead of simply "c:/...".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2

Comment: Be aware, of course, that this *won't* work for anyone viewing your webpage from a computer besides yours.

Answer (score 3):

You should'nt refer to the root of your computer (`c:/`), but the root of the hosting.

```
<img src="/jquery/chapter-1/begin/images/img_0229.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Web URLs don't use drive letters:

`<img src="c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/images/img_0229.jpg">` <-- this is wrong